# Woocommerce - Exempt VAT in Some Shipping Methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In case of shipping to specific countries we have a function that exempts VAT. However, we need to keep VAT in case the shipping method chosen is Local Pickup. Therefore, we have the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'disable_vat_local_pickup' );
  
function disable_vat_local_pickup( $available_gateways ) {
    
   $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
   $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
   if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
       WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
       }     
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work when the checkout page loads. If then i change the chosen shipping method it works fine.

Comment: kindly explain better what behaviour you are expecting and what you are having

Comment: Hi Dr Deo,
What I'm expecting is when the user in checkout chooses Standard Shipping to have the VAT deducted, when he chooses Local Pickup to have the VAT added. (Another function is carrying out the VAT deduction process for specific countries)

What is actually happening right now is that when the checkout page loads, the above functionality is not taking place until i change the shipping choice. ie if i change from standard shipping to local pickup and then back again, it works fine. 

I hope that was clear. I'm happy to clarify more if needed.